# How do I add an extra signing cert to an existing gem?

Tags: ruby, security, rubygems

I've been added as a contributor to an existing project which has a signing certificate attached to the gem. I'll be pushing the next release so I need to add my cert to the gem. When I follow the instructions at http://guides.rubygems.org/security/#building-gems everything is fine up till I reach point 4 and run `gem build`… the following error presents itself:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Security::Exception)
> invalid signing chain: certificate (my details) was not issued by (existing cert owner's details)

I've never added a second cert to an existing gem, does anyone know what the next step is? Does the existing cert owner need to do something? Is a project supposed or able to have more than one cert?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you self-issued your own cert, and it's complaining that the cert chain is broken as a result. The gem's owner should issue your cert using their own as the certification authority.

https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/

It can be done using `openssl`. The docs for doing so are - unfortunately - abysmally bad and the steps you need to take to do so are hairy - to put it mildly. [Possible walkthrough here](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/).

Comment: It's the package manager (Rubygems) that creates the cert, but I don't know what it's doing under the hood so I'll check that out and see if the walkthrough helps me out and get back to you, thanks!